# angular ngSrc doesn't work with html video tag

Tags: html, angularjs

I am trying to load a list of video on a page after uploaded video :

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="video" class="col-sm-2 control-label control-image">video</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        <ul id="video" ng-repeat="video in vm.item.video" ng-if="vm.item.video.length > 0">
            <li>
                <video width="400" controls><source ng-src="{{vm.uploadDomain + video}}" type="video/mp4">> </video>
                </video>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group" ng-class="{'true': '', 'false': 'has-error'}[vm.isValidated('video')]">
    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label control-image">upload</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        <dt-file-uploader  mode="basic"
                          ng-model="vm.item.video"
                          setting="vm.uploader_video"></dt-file-uploader>
    </div>
</div>
```

but it doesn't work, It fail to load the source of these video , what can I do to fix this problem?

Comment: what does vm.uploadDomain contains? have you checked the video is in the path the hltml is searching for ? What error do you get?

Comment: Probably not a problem but `ng-if="vm.item.video.length > 0"` is completely redundant

Comment: You're also potentially adding **multiple** elements with the `id="video"`

Comment: vm.uploadDomain is a domain and video contains a list of directory path

Comment: I can print out the path etc http://teamb.xxxx.net/upload/xxxx/1488363318575.mp4 by label tag but It fail to load the video if using ng-src

Comment: no error, only the player is loaded but the src tag is disapper

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can create a custom filter like this.

```
.filter("trustUrl", function($sce) {
    return function(Url) {
        return $sce.trustAsResourceUrl(Url);
    };
});
```

in the html add filter in src

```
<video width="400" controls>
   <source ng-src="{{vm.uploadDomain + video | trustUrl}}" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```